# Should the variable be locked?

Tags: c#, locking

I have come heir to the following class which loads an XML file from the **file system** and then provides access to the XML. This is used in an ASP.NET MVC application. The intention is obviously to only load the document once per application context. The misnamed parameter xml in the LoadXml method is actually a full path - c:\a\b\c\d\file.xml

```
public class XmlParseService
{
    static XmlDocument xdoc;
    private static object lockobject = new object();

    internal static bool IsdocumentFound
    {
        get
        {
            return xdoc != null;
        }
    }
    internal static void LoadXml(String xml)
    {
        if (xdoc == null)
            xdoc = new XmlDocument();

        xdoc.Load(xml);
    }


    public static XmlNodeList GetNodes(string xpath)
    {
        if (xdoc == null)
            return null;

        lock (lockobject)
        {
            return xdoc.SelectNodes(xpath);
        }
    }

    public static String GetInnerText(string xpath)
    {
        if (xdoc == null)
            return String.Empty;

        lock (lockobject)
        {
            XmlNode node = xdoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
            if (node == null)
                return String.Empty;

            return node.InnerText;
        }
    }

    public static String GetAttributeText(string xpath, string attribute)
    {
        if (xdoc == null)
            return String.Empty;

        lock (lockobject)
        {
            XmlNode node = xdoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
            if (node == null)
                return String.Empty;

            return node.Attributes[attribute].InnerText;
        }
    }

    internal static void LoadXml(FileStream fileStream)
    {
        if (xdoc == null)
            xdoc = new XmlDocument();

        xdoc.Load(fileStream);
    }

    public static string[] GetValues(string xpath)
    {
        lock (lockobject)
        {
            XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes(xpath);

            if (nodes == null)
                return new String[] { };

            string[] s = new string[nodes.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
                s[i] = nodes[i].InnerText;

            return s;
        }
    }

}
```

I can't see why in the method LoadXml that the code is not surrounded by

```
lock (lockobject)
{
    ....
}
```

and also why the `if (xdoc == null)` statements are not wrapped with a lock statement.

Should they be? If not, why should they not? Does it actually need to use `lock` statements?

Comment: That's a very weird attempt at a singleton. All that locking suggest this was thought for a single-threading environment and was patched as bugs were reported. I'd suggest you to make the xdoc variable instance instead of static and fix all other methods as correspond

Answer (score 0):

> I can't see why in the method LoadXml that the code is not surrounded by [...]

Presumably the caller knows something special about that situation.  For example, it might be the case that the XML is only ever loaded in the application start event of the application, and at that point the author knows that there won't ever be any other threads trying to access that value.  Of course, adding the locking back in, even if you know there won't be contention, isn't a terrible idea as the absolutely miniscule cost of taking out the lock isn't much in exchange for the piece of mind of knowing that someone calling the method when they shouldn't won't break the code.

> why the if (xdoc == null) statements are not wrapped with a lock statement.

This is an optimization.  It's not really a *necessary* one, given the previously mentioned extremely small costs of taking out a lock, but in this particular case since assignments of references are atomic, either the variable will be `null` or non-null, it won't ever have an invalid value as a result of an in-progress assignment, so while I don't think it's a *worthwhile* optimization, it looks valid.

Comment: Once loaded, the content of the xml document never changes. I cant see why the locks are actually needed - is it because it provides a performance benefit?

Comment: @JamesCulshaw XmlDocument is not documented as being safe to use from multiple threads.  It might be, but if it it's, since it's not publicly stated in the documentation, it would be subject to change, and not safe to rely on.